# Passing a variable to DateTime.strptime results in TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-4

I would like to retrieve a date from my database, that is saved as a unix timestamp and convert it into YYYY/MM/DD format.

```
DateTime.strptime('1462406400','%s')
=> Thu, 05 May 2016 00:00:00 +0000
```

But when I pass a variable that contains the unix timestamp I receive an error message

**In the View**

```
<div>Your first invoice will be due <%= DateTime.strptime(sub.start_date,'%s') %></div>
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Fixnum into String
```

What is the correct way to pass `sub.start_date` to `DateTime.strptime`?

Comment: What data type is `sub.start_date`? Is it already a `DateTime` or similar? Can you just use `sub.start_date.to_s` without the `DateTime.strptime`? Perhaps you also want to look at the [Date#strftime](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-strftime) method.

Comment: `sub.start_date` is saved as an `Integer` value in the database. It returns a value such as `1461801600 `

Comment: Oh of course, the error tells us that. So convert it into a String: `sub.start_date.to_s`

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Somehow converting an integer to a string to convert it to a date seems very counter-intuitive but it works.

Comment: Yeah I agree -- perhaps Matt's answer below might be a little more direct and should be accepted, if his assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming this is a unix timestamp stored as an integer, you could use `Time.at` (http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Time.html#method-c-at)

```
Time.at(your_integer_value).to_datetime
```

This avoids the int to string necessity of `strptime`, and should therefore be faster.

Comment: Thanks, this solution also works and it requires less code.